# WP получить значение из таблицы базы данных?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Как в WordPress правильно получать значения из кастомной таблицы базы данных.

Вот есть простая таблица `wp_sports_viewer`, с одной строкой данных:
[image: wp_sports_viewer]

Как на фронт вывести значение которое храниться в ячейке `object_last_modified`?

*Пробую, через параметр [wpdb::get_var()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb-get_var) с экранированием, но что-то явно идет не так.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
if( ! empty($wpdb->error) )
    wp_die( $wpdb->error );

$tb_sports = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'sports_viewer';
$modified = 'object_last_modified';
$lastUpdate = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare(`SELECT modified FROM $tb_sports WHERE modified = %s`, $modified));
var_dump($lastUpdate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том что у Вас сам SQL запрос неверно написан и он просто не будет работать и без WordPress.

Давайте разберем что же здесь не так. `SELECT modified` -- когда делаете `SELECT` то нужно указывать что конкретно Вы желаете получить, определенную колонку/колонки либо что-то другое (например `COUNT()`), что такое в Вашем случае `modified`, там же нет такой колонки. Далее `WHERE modified = %s", $modified)` где `modified` (а мы выяснили что у нас нет такой колонки) Вы пытаетесь сравнить как раз с названием колонки которая Вам нужна `object_last_modified`. Оператор WHERE используется для фильтрации результатов, и там обычно указывается какое-то условие, например `WHERE id = 1` или `WHERE object_last_modified BETWEEN '2021-12-25 00:00:00' AND '2022-12-25 23:59:59'`.

На самом деле все гораздо проще:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'sports_viewer';
$result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT object_last_modified FROM $table_name");
```

Так как Вам нужен просто первый результат, то мы можем не указывать `WHERE`, так как Вы хотите получить результат не относящийся к определенному временному промежутку или с определенным ID.

Comment: Спасибо, а ещё уточнение, в описании к данной функции пишут, что необходимо выполнять экранирование от возможных SQL инъекций, необходимо ли это для таких примеров с `$wpdb->get_var` делать если это из админки?

Comment: Все верно, но в данном случае Вы ничего не передаете и экранировать нечего. Если бы Вы передавали туда например ID, то нужно было бы экранировать `$wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT object_last_modified FROM $table_name WHERE id = %d", $id));` и да, для админки это тоже стоит использовать.